# CsharpCodeProvider target .net framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, csharpcodeprovider, .net-4.8

My .net 4.8 code compiles properly and `_ = "test";` doesn't throw an error when using this in visual studio. However when using CsharpCodeProvider this doesn't compile. (this can be easily verified by commenting out this line in the string. How can I tell the CodeProvider to use .net framework 4.8? I know there is a flag that can be set using compiler options but this throws an error about missing csc.exe when using v4.8.

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _ = "test";
            var code = @"
    public class Abc {
       public string Get() { return ""abc""; }
        public string Test(){
            _ = ""test"";
            return ""test"";
        }
    }
";

            var options = new CompilerParameters() { };
            options.GenerateExecutable = false;
            options.GenerateInMemory = false;

            var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider() { };
            var compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

            var type = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Abc");
            var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            var method = type.GetMethod("Test");
            var result = method.Invoke(abc, null);

            Console.WriteLine(result); //output: abc
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not possible.  CSharpCodeProvider always uses the installed version of the .NETFramework and compiles with C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe.  As it tells you when you run it, it is frozen to target C# language version 5.  For a higher version you need to use Roslyn.

Comment: I have tried to do so with Roslyn but also failed to be able to target .net 4.8